# Renaming SQL Server database and MVC5

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, model-view-controller

For reasons not worth going into, I had to rename a Microsoft SQL Server database that an ASP.NET MVC project was using. I thought that, on the MVC side, this would be something as trivial as changing the connection string in the web.config. Alas, no.

The database name went from `myproject.MODELS.OSESDBCONTEXT` to `myproject`.

So, I changed the default connection block in the web.config to reflect that, all else being equal:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory  
        type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=machine.company.com;Initial Catalog=MyProject;User ID=someuser; Password=somepassword@;MultipleActiveResultSets=False" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

It seems to be failing to connect to the database, but since it can't find the database it is attempting to create a new one but it fails because the `.mdf` file is already present. However this isn't the issue, it should be connecting to SQL Server. 
This is the error I get when running the web page:

> Cannot create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyProject.Models.OSesDBContext.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.

Comment: the question is much about entity framework than mvc

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish what you're after by doing a database attachment.

Can you try to reattach it via SQL Server Management Studio or through T-SQL?

First, copy your mdf and ldf files to something new (name them relative to a new database you'll attach them as).

Then in the Attach Databases screen:

- Enter your new name for the database in the `Attach As` field in the top frame
- In the bottom frame, browse to both the new mdf file and the new ldf file you just created.
- You should then have a newly attached database.

Comment: This seems promising. I can connect to the renamed DB through MS-SSMS and through the Visual Studio Server Explorer. 

However, I don't see the "Attach DataBases" screen in Visual Studio. This may be my misunderstanding though.

The database does not exist on my local machine. It is on a server, which I don't admin. I'm not sure that the underlying file names should matter in this case. 

I'm just looking for a way to point the project at the new DB name. But, MVC is having it.

Comment: I imagine this would need to be done using SQL Server Management Studio, I don't think the tools to perform the database attachment will be in  Visual Studio's database tools.

Comment: The database was renamed via SMS already. The issue is getting my MVC app to talk to the renamed DB.

Comment: It seems like something might have gone wrong with the rename because the your error makes it seem as though it cannot locate the database. Is the name correct in sys.databases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think database name should be specified in defaultConnectionFactory - it seems like it's about server in the first place.

Database name should be specified elsewhere, e.g. see the possible options here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.

I can only suspect the old database name is still somewhere in the places mentioned above. Have you tried to search for the old name in the sources?

Comment: The link wasn't very helpful for this issue, unless I am missing something. It mostly talked about making changes to the DB. Unfortunately, I just want MVC to connect to the new DB, and it is not having it. Somewhere, it still seems to be insisting that it wants to connect to the old one and try to recreate it if it can't.

Comment: Why not to search then where is that "somewhere" where the old database name is mentioned? Based on the article, it could be 1) name of the context class 2) base constructor argument of the context 3) connection string in the connectionStrings section. I cannot know which one is used in your code, but you can check, or, in the worst case, search in files for the old db name. What I'm pretty sure about, connection factory is NOT the place, so no wonder it doesn't react on that change you did.

Comment: so, the only place that the old DB name was used, in its entirety (myproject.models,osesdbcontext) was in the webconfig. I changed it to "myproject" after the rename.

I can find no other reference to the old name anywhere.

Comment: "myproject.models,osesdbcontext" looks very much like option 1. 
Can you specify db name explicitly in the constructor?

Note that if you rename database, its files are not renamed - so your myproject should still has osesdbcontext-named mdf and ldf.
You can rename those in SSMS, but I expect EF to still use the database named against your dbcontext - unless you explicitly set the correct db name